# fetching from Local Json in React usinguseEffect and componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, json

I am trying to fetch some data from local JSON to React. I have searched and come to two methods: useEffect and componentDidMount. Which one should I use?

Comment: These are different things. `useEffect` - hook for functional components, `componentDidMount` - lifecycle method in the class component. Which to use depend on how you implement your app. It's better to provide some code and more details to be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use functional component (React version >= 16.8) use `UseEffect` and If you use class component you should use `componentDidMount`.